# Rails does not read the code from the file enviroment.rb when I use the production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, environment, production

I am using rails version 3.0.3.
If I run the server in the development environment, everything works ok, but when trying to run in a production environment then rails skip read the code from the file /config/ enviroment.rb.
I have the following error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/herman/WORK/bloomnet/broniszeKwiaty/broniszeKwiaty/broniszeKwiaty/app/models/produkt.rb:10: uninitialized constant Produkt::GRUPY_PRODUKTOWE (NameError)
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `eager_load!'
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `eager_load!'
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
        from /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
        from /home/herman/WORK/bloomnet/broniszeKwiaty/broniszeKwiaty/broniszeKwiaty/config/environment.rb:5
        from /home/herman/WORK/bloomnet/broniszeKwiaty/broniszeKwiaty/broniszeKwiaty/config.ru:3
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from /home/herman/WORK/bloomnet/broniszeKwiaty/broniszeKwiaty/broniszeKwiaty/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from /home/herman/WORK/bloomnet/broniszeKwiaty/broniszeKwiaty/broniszeKwiaty/config.ru:1
```

My enviroment.rb looks like:

```
    # Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
BroniszeKwiaty::Application.initialize!


#exceptions
CONTROLLERS_NAMES = {"menu" => "menu_index"}
CONTROLLERS_NAMES_IN_VIEW = {"names" => "imieniny", "produkty" => "towary"}

CONTROLLERS_HIDDEN = [7, 15, 18]

$ZABRONIONE_ROZSZERZENIA = %w{ php rb cgi py shtml pl }

# Ustawienia dla zdjec :


$HEIGHT_MINI3 = 106
$WIDTH_MINI3 = 106

$HEIGHT_CAL = 120
$WIDTH_CAL = 120

$HEIGHT_MINI2 = 163
$WIDTH_MINI2 = 163

$HEIGHT_MINI = 174
$WIDTH_MINI = 174

$WIDTH_MATCHED = 500
$HEIGHT_MATCHED = 300

$WIDTH = 800
$HEIGHT = 600
##################################
$default_cal_path = '/images/cal.png'
$default_cal2_path = '/images/cal2.png'



MENU_URL = { 8 => '/kontakt', 2=> "/informacje", 6=>"/najemcy", 5 =>'/hale', 3 => '/oferta-handlowa', 7 => '/multimedia'} #zastepuje adres /podstrony/:id na wartosc z tablicy (url(/podstrony/2)  => url(/informacje))


$ID_HK = 3 #id hali kwiatow w bazie bronisz
$ID_WK = 8 #id wiaty kwiatowej w bazie bronisz
PELNA_NAZWA_HALI = {3 => "hala kwiatowa",8 => "wiata kwiatowa"}
SKROT_NAZWY_HALI = {3 => "HK",8 => "WK"}

GRUPY_PRODUKTOWE = ["opakowania do kwiatów","kwiaty cięte, zieleń","rośliny doniczkowe", "dodatki kwiatowe"]
```

Many thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.. sometimes, ruby takes a wrong turn when deciding where to look for a constant. You defined the constant GRUPY_PRODUKTOWE globally and you probably access it within the Product model with just "GRUPY_PRODUKTOWE". Try "::GRUPY_PRODUKTOWE" so it knows to look for it in the global scope.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, your e solution did not work. I moved the array to the model and now starts the server in a production environment. Now I have another problem, but i'll write about it in a new question. THX